# Pass string into variable in sass mixin

Tags: sass

I have a very simple mixin which looks like this:

```
@mixin global( $variable-name ) {
    font-size:   #{$variable-name}-font-size;
}
```

I have previously defined variable $input-font-size and pass it into the mixin in the following format

```
@include global( input );
```

Problem is that the sass is not converting it and browser returns :

> font-size:input-font-size

How should I write my mixin to actually return the value from $input-font-size please?

Thank you for your advice in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create a dynamic variables in sass.

'#{}' means it will convert whatever attribute to its plain css form, it won't be treated as a variable it will be treated as a text.

What you can do is create a map for the list of properties and call them inside the mixin.

```
$input-font-size: 16px;
$textarea-font-size: 14px;


$var-map: (
  input: $input-font-size, 
  textarea:  $textarea-font-size,
);

@mixin global( $variable-name ) {
    font-size:  map-get($var-map, $variable-name);
}

body {
  @include global( input );
}
```

or if you dont want to create the map then you can simply pass the variable name in the mixin

```
@mixin sec( $variable-name ) {
  font-size: $variable-name;
}
.text-area {
  @include sec( $textarea-font-size );
}
```

Sample pen
https://codepen.io/srajagop/pen/aWedNM

Comment: Thanks @karthick. This will work just fine with a small mixin. Problem is that my mixin is huge and the map would go forever.

Comment: hmm. if you want to have short notation of the variable then this is the way to go. Or else you can always pass the variable name directly mixin global( $variable-name ) {  font-size: $variable-name;
} and include it like include global( $input-font-size );

Comment: you will still be having as much variables in the sass files right? so why does creating a map a big task. You can create one var file where all the variables are present and then one map file with the same variables in it. Just that you will have a key prepended to the variable.

Comment: Thank you  @karthick. The actual mixin looks like this https://gist.github.com/dompl/d8947dfed8feba487940d841752321a2

I would like to change the variables for i.e select or textarea. With all fairness I never used map hence my confusion. Do you think there is a better way of solving it?

Comment: hi @Dom you cant create dynamic variables in sass. That's the reason I suggested map. If you are worried about creating a huge map. You can always create smaller maps based on some groups and then access it.

Comment: After some more research that seems to be the most reasonable way. Thank you!